# JMSMessageID null received in MDB

Tags: jms, listener, message-queue, weblogic12c

While receiving the message in MDB I am getting null messageId:

`String sMessageID = message.getJMSMessageID();`

My MDB is deployed in weblogic server and when I call `message.getJMSMessageID()` I get the following exception:

> 11:30:39.761 ERROR c.c.s.l.t.m.l.AbstractMessageListener - Exception occured while processing the message java.lang.NumberFormatException: [JMSClientExceptions:055100]Cannot convert null to a long.
>         at weblogic.jms.common.TypeConverter.toLong(TypeConverter.java:162)
>         at weblogic.jms.common.MessageImpl.getLongProperty(MessageImpl.java:1104)
>         at com.demo.transition.mdb.listener.AbstractMessageListener.onMessage(AbstractMessageListener.java:67)
>         at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor415.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>         at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:310)
>         at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
>         at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
>         at com.oracle.pitchfork.intercept.MethodInvocationInvocationContext.proceed(MethodInvocationInvocationContext.java:103)
>         at com.oracle.pitchfork.intercept.JeeInterceptorInterceptor.invoke(JeeInterceptorInterceptor.java:117)
>         at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
>         at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)
>         at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
>         at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
>         at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy284.onMessage(Unknown Source)
>         at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.MDListener.execute(MDListener.java:575)
>         at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.MDListener.transactionalOnMessage(MDListener.java:477)
>         at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.MDListener.onMessage(MDListener.java:375)
>         at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.onMessage(JMSSession.java:4855)
>         at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.execute(JMSSession.java:4529)
>         at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.executeMessage(JMSSession.java:3976)
>         at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.access$000(JMSSession.java:120)
>         at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession$UseForRunnable.run(JMSSession.java:5375)
>         at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:553)
>         at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:312)
>         at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:264)

Comment: Which version of weblogic?

Comment: i m using weblogic 12c

Comment: 12.1.3 or 12.2.1?

Comment: I tested on WLS 12.1.3 and the message ID is not null.

Comment: I m using WebLogic Server Version: 12.1.2.0.0